# How to ICE Restart in Android peerconnection client?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, apprtc

I created a webrtc android application using libjinge library, my issue is unable to reconnect after a network failure,In browser used 'icerestart',  how to ICE Restart in Android peerconnection client?

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make my answer an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the android peer connection object doesn't have any `icerestart()` method we have to do a workaround in our code to re-establish the connection.

Steps should be:

1. Put additional constraint:

```
constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart","true"));
```

2. Create offer again using that constraints:

```
peerConnection.createOffer(new YourSdpObserver(),constraints);
```

3. Set generated sdp to peerConnection using setLocalDescription.:

```
peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new YourSdpObserver(),sdp);
```

4. Send it to the remote peer.